# Do you have to pay for the iPhone SDK for each developer?

Tags: iphone

Is there a link to how I can get the 3.0 SDK without having to pay a second time? I'm joining another guy at my company on a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the 3.0 SDK by logging into the developer portal.

Additionally, you can use the developer portal to add additional developers to your company's team.

There is no fee when adding another team member.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to pay for each developer, they can download the sdk themselves when they create a free developer account.  You can also add their device id to your account so that they can test apps on their iphones or ipod touch devices